# Problems verifying elements on page using have_css

Tags: cucumber, capybara

When I go to a page I wish to verify that certain elements are present. I am having problems finding an element on a page using should have_css.

So my code looks like this: 
      should have_css('name')

However this does not find the element. Strange thing is, I am able to interact with the field name using fill_in. For example the following:
    fill_in('name', :with => 'testname')
results in the field been populated!! Has anyone seen anything like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**

The css-selector used in

```
should have_css('name')
```

is incorrect. This says to find an element with type "name" (ie a  tag).

In contrast, when you do

```
fill_in('name', :with => 'testname')
```

Capybara looks for a text field or text area with its name, id or label text being "name" (ie , , etc.).

As you can see using 'name' as the locator is not the same for the two methods.

**Solution**

If you want for something with an id of "name", you want to do:

```
should have_css('#name')
```

If you want for something with a name of "name", you want to do:

```
should have_css('[name=name]')
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks Justin. The second solution you listed was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the detailed explanation also.